# Haver Sine Distance in Google BigQuery

Tags: mysql, math, google-bigquery

I am trying to get haversine distance between two points(lat,long) in Google BigQuery.

Previously I used the following code in MySQL, which worked fine:

```
(((ACOS( (SIN(radians(pickup_latitude)) * SIN(radians(dropoff_latitude))) + 
(COS(radians(pickup_latitude)) * COS(radians(dropoff_latitude))
* COS(radians(dropoff_longitude)-radians(pickup_longitude))) )) * 6371))
```

But the same code showing this error-

> Function not found: radians at [6:19]"

when I run it in Google BigQuery. How do I convert the MySQL version of code into Google BigQuery version?

Comment: So you will have to check the documentation for the new database to see what the function, if it exists, is called and how to use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BigQuery Standard SQL - you can use [ST_DISTANCE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_distance) function to calculate distance between two points as in example below

```
SELECT ST_DISTANCE(
  ST_GEOGPOINT(pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude), 
  ST_GEOGPOINT(dropoff_longitude, dropoff_latitude)
) AS distance 
FROM ...
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you!